# open and close time in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have project in django rest framework that has a `Store` model, and I want the owner of stores to be able to enter the opening and closing hours and days that they work in their profiles of website.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow store owners to be able to update or partially update just their stores, so you may need to look at some sort of custom permission class - whereby you would need to allow object level permissions for editing:

`permissions.py`

```
class OwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.IsAuthenticated):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        user = request.user
        if type(obj) == type(user) and obj == user:
            return True
        return request.method in SAFE_METHODS
```

You would also then need to add the corresponding opening and closing times fields to the Store `models.py` class.

However, handling this may be more complex if you have opening and closing times for, for example, every day of the week, or Christmas day, or Easter etc.

You would likely need an intermediary table which tracks day, as perhaps an integer, e.g., `0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday ... etc`, the "`profile`" field (`ForeignKey` relationship to a `Profile` instance), and the same for the store. Then, allow users to `create_or_update` these entries via RESTful endpoints...

There's certainly a lot to unpack...